# idangerous Swiper swipeto function not working when swiper object name passed as a string

Tags: javascript

```
<script>

var contentSwiperNumber = 'contentSwiper1';


var navSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-nav',{
    scrollContainer: true,

    /*Thumbnails Clicks*/
    onSlideClick: function(){

    <!-- These work fine -->
    contentSwiper1.swipeTo( navSwiper.clickedSlideIndex );
    contentSwiper2.swipeTo( navSwiper.clickedSlideIndex );


    <!-- !!!!Not Working???? contentSwiperNumber.swipeTo ????-->
    contentSwiperNumber.swipeTo( navSwiper.clickedSlideIndex );

    }
    })

</script>
```

Is there a way to reference a swiper object name using a string passed to a variable?

Please see the code above where I pass the string:

var contentSwiperNumber = 'contentSwiper1';

in an attempt to reference the swiper object var contentSwiper1

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on what are you trying to do exactly? From what I am seeing over here, You are putting a string value inside **contentSwiperNumber** and trying to call **swipeTo** from it. You are treating a string value as an object with a method in it.

I can say that **contentSwiper1** as a variable (Not the string value) is an object itself like  **navSwiper** in your code. When you call

```
contentSwiper1.swipeTo(index)
```

here **contentSwiper1** is a slider object. But when you call

```
contentSwiperNumber.swipeTo(index)
```

You are calling the string.  Imagine you are doing

```
'contentSwiper1'.swipeTo(index)
```

does that work? I do not think so.

So, either save the objects in a session like [amplifyjs](http://amplifyjs.com/) which will let you do something like this:

```
var contentSwiper1 = new Slider('.contentSwiper1', options);
amplify.store('contentSwiper1', contentSwiper1);
```

To retrieve the object you need, you can use:

```
var contentSwiperNumber = 'contentSwiper1';
var swiperObject = amplify.store(contentSwiperNumber);
swiperObject.swipeTo(index);
```

Also, you can use **window** object to save the swipers you create and then write some logic that does a switch case to return the object you need depending on the **contentSwiperNumber**

I hope this helps.